# Error when creating cloud task: "2 UNKNOWN: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-iam, google-cloud-tasks

I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) tutorial (for Node.js) to create Cloud Tasks' HTTP target tasks with the `CreateTask` method. I also did the part for [using authentication tokens](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#token).

Before yesterday I could create tasks without problems, but yesterday I started to get the following error when calling the `createTask()` method:

> 2 UNKNOWN: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant

I read in a [blog](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) that this error is related to google accounts getting "*OAuth2 tokens issued for access to certain products ... revoked [(hence `invalid_grant`)] when a user’s password is changed"*. I haven't changed the password of the google account which is the "owner" of the project where I have the Cloud Tasks API's queue, but the day I started getting the error I did receive an email from google saying that my google account had been successfully recovered (I think that was because I logged into a new device and struggled a bit with two-step authentication, but I did not reset my password or something like that).

I've tried using the gcloud cli to log in again to my account with `gcloud auth login`. I've also tried creating a new queue and a new service account for Cloud Tasks, but I still get the error. According to the blog I mentioned, I suppose the error is related to my google account, but I have no idea of how to solve it.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did your App require user to sign in and grant access?

Comment: My app's users sign in with a google account, but so far I've only been using firebase emulators. Anyhow, my app's user accounts do not interact with the Cloud Task API directly.